# How to use Javascript/JQuery to Simulate a POST Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

I'm attempting to write a script that sends an Ajax POST request.  Part of this request includes a file upload, but because I'm writing a script, I'm looking to send a string instead of a file.  The content type of the upload is `multipart/form-data`.

I found [a tool](http://i-tools.org/base64) to encode the string into its binary base64 version, but I'm still at a loss as to how to take that encoded string and send it as the request payload.

How do I send a string as a file in a POST using either Javascript or JQuery?

Comment: Why does the string need to be a file? Why not just send a string as a string in the request? File creation is more a server-side task anyway.

Comment: I don't need to create a file.  I need to send the string as the request payload, which I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.post()` with `FormData()` to simulate uploads.

```
$.post("path/to/upload", {data: new FormData()}, function (res) {
  // Response
});
```

Make sure that that `FormData()` is taken from an existing form with `enctype="multipart/formdata"`.

Another example would be:

```
var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'file', input.files[0] );

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/script.php',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: How does FormData know that `input.files[0]` is the request payload?

Comment: You need to give specify that bro!